# Running jar file with argument from batch script windows 8

Tags: java, batch-file, windows-8, cmd, windows-8.1

I am trying to run my .jar file with arguments through batch script in Windows 8.

My batch file (run.bat) has the following content:

```
set d=2015-07-07
java -jar my.jar %d%
```

But when I execute run.bat I get the following:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test>run.bat

C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test>set d=2015-07-07

C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test>java -jar my.jar

C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test>2015-07-07
'2015-07-07' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How to execute the whole command together with arguments?

When I run it without batch script through command line then it works:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test>java -jar my.jar 2015-07-07
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test>
```

What I am doing wrong in a batch script?

Comment: Just tried that exact script and it works fine for me (Windows 8.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use batch code

```
@echo off
set "DateOption=2015-07-07"
java.exe -jar my.jar %DateOption%
set "DateOption="
```

or perhaps even better

```
@echo off
set "DateOption=2015-07-07"
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" -jar my.jar %DateOption%
set "DateOption="
```

According to commands output by **cmd.exe** on running your batch file, it looks like there is a character between `my.jar` and `%d%` in second line or between `=` and `2015-07-07` in first line being interpreted as newline by **cmd.exe**. It could be a single carriage return or a single line-feed. And a NULL (byte with value 0) is interpreted by **cmd.exe** as end of string which means also end of line.

Batch files should have DOS/Windows line terminators, i.e. carriage return + line-feed. A line-feed only (UNIX) or carriage return only (old MAC) is not good for batch files.

And batch files must be ASCII/ANSI (OEM) encoded files, i.e. 1 byte per character. Make sure not having UTF-8 or Unicode (UTF-16 Little/Big Endian) selected in the used text editor on using command **Save As** to save the batch file. Many text editors use by default nowadays UTF-8 as encoding which **cmd.exe** does not support.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was removing the echo statement, and making the call to `java` the first line of the program.